# Making x the subject

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Was creating a few practice problems for a test and this one seemed to be very difficult. I could not find a way for $x$ to be subject without also having $x$ on both sides of the equation.

$\frac y{(x-2)}=5+\frac2{3-x}$

$x=?$

Comment: Looks like you might end up with a quadratic equation if you want to solve for x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this equation:

Move the terms containing $x$ to the same side, yielding $\frac y{x-2}+\frac2{x-3}=5$

Cross multiply the fractions to get the same denominators, yielding $\frac {y(x-3)}{(x-2)(x-3)}+\frac{2(x-2)}{(x-2)(x-3)}=5$

Combine the numerators: $\frac {y(x-3)+2(x-2)}{(x-2)(x-3)}=5$

Multiply both sides by the denominator: $y(x-3)+2(x-2)=5(x-2)(x-3)$

Distribute: $xy-3y+2x-4=5x^2-25x+30$

Collect terms: $0=5x^2+(-27-y)x+34+3y$

Use the quadratic equation: $x=\frac{27+y\pm\sqrt{(27+y)^2-4(5)(34+3y)}}{10}$

And of course, don't forget to apply domain restrictions: $x\ne2, 3$.